# consulta eloquent tabla pivote

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo las siguientes tablas

```
empresa     | estado_empresa      | estado
 -id           -id_empresa            -id
 -nombre       -id_estado             -estado
               -Fecha_creado
               -Fecha_actualizado
```

en mi sistema, las empresas pasan por los distintos estados, cuando una empresa cambia de estado, se agrega un registro en la tabla intermedia, sin borrar el historial de estados por los que ha pasado esa empresa, ya que lo utilizo en otro módulo donde muestro el historial de estados por los que ha pasado dicha empresa.

ahora bien, para obtener el estado actual de 1 sola empresa realicé siguiente consulta.

```
public static function estado_actual($id){
    $empresa= Empresa::findOrFail($id);
    $estado_actual = $empresa->estados()->orderBy('fecha_creado', 'DESC')->take(1)->get(); //obtiene el estado actual (ultimo registro segun fecha
    return $estado_actual;
}
```

esto funciona perfecto para mi, sin embargo necesito preguntarles lo siguiente:

Teniendo en cuenta la consulta anterior, donde obtengo el estado actual de 1 empresa en especifico...

> ¿cómo puedo obtener el estado actual de todas las empresas al mismo
>   tiempo?
>
> Ej: Necesito obtener la lista de todas las empresas donde su estado
>   actual sea `PROSPECTO`

mi consulta actual

```
-- CONSULTA ESTADO PROSPECTO --

$prospectos = Empresa::with('estados')->selectRaw('distinct empresas.*')->whereHas('estados', function ($query) {
        $query->where('estado_empresa.estado_id', '=', 1)->orderBy('fecha_creado', 'desc');
    })->get();
```

pero no es específico porque si tengo una empresa con dos estados `PROSPECTOS` me duplica la información.

desde ya agradezco su tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

La cláusula DISTINCT es lo que necesitas... A tú consulta, al final, antes del get...
Quedaría tu consulta actual:

```
-- CONSULTA ESTADO PROSPECTO --

$prospectos = Empresa::with('estados')->selectRaw('distinct empresas.*')->whereHas('estados', function ($query) {
        $query->where('estado_empresa.estado_id', '=', 1)->orderBy('fecha_creado', 'desc');
    })->distinct()->get();
```

Un saludo

Comment: gracias por responder, al realizar lo que me indicas, laravel me dice lo siguiente. Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$distinct           donde debo definir distinct?

Comment: Me faltaron los parentesis del distinct. Lo corrijo ya. De todas maneras, te paso la documentación oficial con ejemplos: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#selects